# need to know what is exactly a resizable dynamic data structure

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable, object-oriented-database

I'm a software engineer student, and we are studying C. Actually we are deal with data structure, so in some of my search about hash tables especially linear probing I read the term of  "resizable dynamic data", but hardly I found a good explanation. Please help me to discover more about..

Comment: Where did you read this term? What was the context?

Comment: search the technique linear probing, in the case where array size < items number, so we will need more array size to insert all given items, "if the hash table is implemented as a resizable dynamic data structure it could be made to increase in size automatically when the load factor reaches a certain threshold" ...

Comment: Right, the real term you're looking for is "resizable dynamic data structure". Then it makes more sense, doesn't it?

Comment: yeah it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Probably Dynamic Array's/ Data Structures. ( Any structure whose data
  capacity/values tend to be dynamic in nature)
- In the case of Dictionaries(aka HashMaps), it would be Dynamic Value specification or Dynamic Key access or Dynamic items). The reason is because key access is O(1) time and any key lookup is possible either the key would be Integer or String or SingleCharacter.
- In the case of Rendering( it would be Dynamic Resizing Rendered
  Components).
- In the case of Mobile Development (it would be Dynamic Resizable
  Placement: Check Kivy for this))